# What is the name of this spectacles?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

It has some microscope attached to it:

[image]

What is the name of this spectacles?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I think your question has not been well-received because it is not really about the use of the English language, but about specialized terminology with which only people in a particular field would be familiar. At the least, a good Stack Exchange question should demonstrate what your initial attempts at research have already found. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: You cannot say this spectacles, only these spectacles. It must be plural.

Answer (score 3):

I find these advertised ...

[magnifying glasses loupe lens](https://www.staples.com/Insten-10X-20x-Magnifying-Glasses-Loupe-Lens-LED-Light-Magnifier-for-Jeweler-Watch-Repair/product_2117024?cid=PS:GooglePLAs:2117024&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=2117024&KPID=2117024&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI36aM38vF4QIVOB6tBh1HEggsEAQYCiABEgJM7PD_BwE)

[image: pict]

[Headband Magnifying Glass](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M8NR5GJ)

[image: pict]

[Dental surgical loupes](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Factory-price-Dental-Surgical-Loupes-With_60728957330.html)

[image: pict]

[Vintage surgical glasses](https://microscopestorenyc.com/shop-2/microscope-accessories/vintage-surgical-glasses/)

[image: pict]